# asymptotic curve, line of curvature and planar curve

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curves

I met a problem to prove or disprove that:
a. If a curve is both an asymptotic curve and a line of curvature, then it must be planar.
b. If a curve is planar and an asymptotic curve, then it must be a line.

For a, I show that the derivative of the shape operator along the curve is 0 and concluding that it is true, although I am not fully convinced by my argument. However, for b, I am totally off.

This question is different from [Geodesics and Curves on a Plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754471/geodesics-and-curves-on-a-plane). The condition here is asymptotic, line of curvature and planar, but not geodesic. Please carefully reading the questions.